# Java: pass the same randomly generated number onto another function

Tags: java, random

my question is the following:
How do I use the same random integer twice without it generating a new random number?
this is my code:

```
private static void draw() {
    for (int a=random(2,4); a>0; a--) {
        rectangle(random(0,20), random(0,10));
    }       
}

private static void rectangle(int width, int height) {
    halfRect(width, height);
    halfRect(width, height);

}

private static void halfRect(int width, int height) {
    walkRandom(width, true);
    turnLeft();
    walkRandom(height, true);
}
```

I want to use the in line 3 randomly generated integers in the function rectangle, which calls the function halfRect twice. I want the random integers to stay the same the two times it runs the function, which is not the case with this code. Also I'd rather not use variables, it's a school assignment and they they it could be done without variables.
Any suggestions?
thanks!

Comment: You may create variable and store value there

Comment: Are you saying you think the two calls to `halfRect` from `rectangle` won't use the same numbers? Because that's not possible. Each call to `rectangle` may have different numbers, but within `rectangle` there's no way those numbers are changing

Comment: @CupawnTae is right; the method parameters have the results of the random calls bound to them, so they cant change during execution of the method without explicit change.

Comment: Presumably `walkRandom` is also introducing a random element - could that be causing you confusion? I.e. even though `halfRect` receives the same parameters, it will `walk` a random amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about what you're asking, but I think this will solve your problem.  We just need to add another level of indirection with another method.  This doesn't add any more local variables (as requested).  Instead, it uses method parameters.

```
private static void draw() {
    drawWith(random(0,20), random(0,10));
}

private static void drawWith(int width, int height) {
    for (int a=random(2,4); a>0; a--) {
        rectangle(width, height);
    }       
}

private static void rectangle(int width, int height) {
    halfRect(width, height);
    halfRect(width, height);

}

private static void halfRect(int width, int height) {
    walkRandom(width, true);
    turnLeft();
    walkRandom(height, true);
}
```

Comment: Although i like your code better, it functions the same way as OP; the random calls are evaluated and bound to parameters of the rectangle method, so they dont change.

Comment: @BenKnoble I'm having trouble understanding OP's original question, but I think that's the point.  It's not meant to change.  But the way OP did it, it was generating new random numbers with each iteration of the for loop.  With my code, it's using the same ones.  Although now I realize that it's just going to draw 2 rectangles over top of each other so I don't really understand the goal here, TBH.

Comment: Yeah. It sounded to me like he was concerned that by using random as parameters, each halfrect call inside rectangle would evaluate a random, which it wont.

Comment: @BenKnoble and other Ben note the `walkRandom` in `halfRect` - it probably won't just draw the same thing each time, depending on what that method does - so I suspect that's the original problem.